# How can I stop the second tab from being automatically selected in EasyTabs?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make tabs and am using easytabs. By the below code, the second option is the default selected tab.

I want the first tab to be selected as an active tab. I did it before, but unfortunately I missed the file. Now I am struggling to do it again. Please tell me how to make the first tab (statistics) to be selected at first as a default tab. Now the second tab which (followup) is the default selected tab.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US"> 
    <head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11"> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <script src="js/ajax_request.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

        <script src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script src="js/jquery.hashchange.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.easytabs.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <style> 
            #tab-container { border: solid 0px; height: auto; }
            #tab-container ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
            #tab-container ul li { display: inline-block; background:#464646 ; border:  1px; border-bottom: none; font-color:#000000;}
            #tab-container ul li a { display: block; padding: 5px; outline: none; }
            #tab-container ul li a:hover { text-decoration: none;background-color:#30A4B1; }
            #tab-container ul li.active-tab {   padding-top: 6px; position: relative; top: 1px; font-color:#000000; }
            #tab-container ul li a.active-tab { font-weight: bold;position:relative; }
            #tab-container .panel { border: ; padding: 0 10px; }
            #tab-container ul li a.active { background-color:#30A4B1; color:#ffffff; }

        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
          $(document).ready(function(){ $('#tab-container').easytabs({
            updateHash: false,
            tabActiveClass:'active',


          }); });
</script>         
    </head>
<body>
        <div id="tab-container"  >
        <ul style="float:right;">
        <li><a href="" data-target="#tab2">Statistics
    </a>        
        </li>           
        <li><a href="" data-target="#that-other-tab">Followup
                <span class="notification-bubble" title="Notifications" style="background-color: rgb(239, 51, 14); display: inline;" id="countOrder"><?php echo $countOrder;?></span>           
        </a>        
        </li>       
        <li><a href="" data-target="#pay-tab" class="tabs">Payment</a></li>
           </ul><br/><br/><hr/>

        <div class="panel-container">
        <div id="tab2">
            <iframe src="charts/chart_main.php" width="100%" height="1000px" scrolling="no" style="border:0px; margin:0px;">
                </iframe>
                </div>

            <div id="that-other-tab">
            <iframe src="followup/follow_grid.php" width="100%" height="500px" scrolling="no" style="border:0px; margin:0px;">
                </iframe>
                </div>
                                <div id="pay-tab">
            <iframe src="pay_grid.php" width="100%" height="500px" scrolling="no" style="border:0px; margin:0px;">
                </iframe>
                </div>      
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a bunch of different classes, but from the looks of it you can just remove the `active` class from the second tab and then add the `active` class to the first tab. Simple stuff :)

Hope this helps.

---

### Edit —

I think i just figured out something in this plugin. You want it to be on the first tab even when you refresh the page, correct? If so, you just need to turn the `updateHash` setting to `false`. Replace your current `<script>` with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tab-container').easytabs({
        animate: false,
        tabActiveClass: 'active',
        updateHash: false
    });
});
</script>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks nathan...i was stupid to ask this here actually...i just removed the active class in the tab-container and it just works perfectly..:) thanks for remiding me mate.!

Comment: edited the change above, may be it could help someone look for the same ;)

Comment: @Bala.C - No problem :) In about 10 minutes (when the system will allow you) please remember to click the check mark next to this answer. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, so the whole thing still isn't working? Okay, I'll edit my answer. Could you provide a link to the plugin page so I can see what the plugin does and how it works? Is [this](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/jquery-easytabs-plugin/demo-multiple-on-same-page/#3-lastly) the plugin that you're using?

Comment: here is the link for easytabs which am using....   http://plugins.jquery.com/content/easytabs-233

Comment: Okay, I just downloaded the .zip file of the plugin. I have a question, in the address bar, is there a `#` and then the page/tab name? If so, that's why it is loading like that. For example, when you click tabs they put a hash and then the page name. Maybe that is making it be on the second tab already? If so, remove the `#` and everything after it out of the address bar and then refresh the page. That should fix it :)

Comment: its true its making changes in the url...but it breaks the links if i do that..!

Comment: Hmmm... try [clicking here](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/jquery-easytabs-plugin/demo-multiple-on-same-page/). What tab is it on? Now, [click here](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/jquery-easytabs-plugin/demo-multiple-on-same-page/#that-other-tab). What tab is it on then?

Comment: I think i have taken that id-bug file in the examples. anyhow..i think it will help if i can make the first tab to get selected onload using jquery..I think it will solve if the first tab's class changes to active onload..can this help ?

Comment: Well, there is probably jQuery to do this, but when you go to that first link above that I posted, you'll see that it is on the first tab. Those hashes in the URL are to keep it on the same tab when you refresh the page. When you load the page regularly, it wont be on that tab correct? I'll try writing a code that will force it to stay on the first tab when the page loads if that's what you want.

Comment: nope you can do that by just addig updateHash: false to the document ready.! that didn't solved the issue actually though i tried

Comment: @Bala.C Oh, whoops. So, what do you want then? You need to remove the hash even after you set that setting because the hash will still make it go to the second tab. If you remove the hash from the URL, it shouldn't go to the second tab.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5255/discussion-between-nathan-and-bala-c)